# Cheapest way to access and modify a struct

Tags: solidity, storage, arrays, struct

I am using solidity 0.8.10.

In my contract I have a state variable struct:

```
struct Product {
    uint id_prod;
    address payable producer_addr;
    address payable owner_addr;
    bool onSale;
    }
```

and a state variable array of products:

```
Product[] public ProductList;
```

and a function that allows to modify the attributes of the product. Nothing really complex.

Considering the cost in deploying and using the contract, I think there are two ways of changing the attributes of the product.

**Solution 1**, by using a storage variable:

```
Product storage _product = ProductList[_id_product];
_product.owner_addr = payable(msg.sender);
_product.onSale = false;
```

**Solution 2**, without a storage variable:

```
ProductList[_id_product].owner_addr = payable(msg.sender);
ProductList[_id_product].onSale = false;
```

Which solution is the cheapest, cleanest, most advisable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try your smart contract code with a different implementation and I saw this stats:

Solution 1: `65937 gas`

Solution 2: `72073 gas`

As you can see from the gas numbers, the first solution is better than second solution. Another advantages, I saw are the solution 2 for access to the data and initialize the storage variable uses more time `SSTORE` and `SLOAD` opcodes. On the contrary, the solution 1 use sload and sstore fewer times than solution 2.

Note: Number about OPCODES calls depends also from your implementation!

To see OPCODES, you can enable **DEBUGGER** plugin on the Remix IDE and execute your function (after deployed the smart contract). After executed it, copy the transaction hash and go into debugger plugin and paste it.